# Convert $x()'s return value to individual strings in browser console (one liner)?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome, xpath

How can I convert the return value of an XPath search `$x()`, when executed in a browser console, to individual strings so that I can perform string manipulations on the result in a "one-liner"?

Imagine that I run a `$x()` and the result is three values:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I then want to extract the first letter from each of these result, using something like `'abc'.match(".")`. It has to be a "one-liner" because the purpose is to distribute it to non-technical users that should be able to just copy-paste it into the console.

Error handling is not necessary.

Comment: What is `$x()`? Have you tried `$x().split(' ').map(s => s.match("."))`?

Comment: @jabaa `$x()` executes an XPath search in the console. It takes an XPath as argument.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried the snippet from my first comment? Maybe you need `$x().map(s => s.match("."))`, `Array.from($x()).map(s => s.match("."))` or `Array.prototype.map.call($x(), s => s.match("."))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Google Chrome console one-liner,

```
$x('//span').map(e => e.textContent.charAt(0))
```

will return an array of the first characters of the text content of every `span` element of the current page.  Update the XPath side (`//span`) or the JavaScript side (`.map(e => e.textContent.charAt(0)))`) as needed for your particular case.